# How to combine tf.data.Dataset and tf.estimator.DNNRegressor properly

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-estimator

I am currently learning to use tensorflow and have troubles getting started.
I would like to use the newest API, namely estimator and dataset. But if I run the code presented below I get an Error.

On the tensorflow page https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/DNNRegressor I found, that "The function should construct and return one of the following: * A tf.data.Dataset object: Outputs of Dataset object must be a tuple (features, labels) with same constraints as below."

I thought my code would provide that, but there seems to be a problem and I am out of ideas.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
def input_evaluation_set():
    data = [0.0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1]
    labels = []
    for d in data:
        labels.append(1)
    return tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.constant(data), tf.constant(labels)))

point = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('points')
estimator = tf.estimator.DNNRegressor(feature_columns = [point],hidden_units = [100,100,100])

estimator.train(input_fn = input_evaluation_set)
```

I expect to run a training session on a deep neural network with 3 hidden layers a' 100 neurons in order to approximate the 'constant 1' function;
instead I get the Error "ValueError: features should be a dictionary of 'Tensor's. Given type: class, 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use .batch on your database in order to have the right format.

The following is working on my computer:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def basic_dataset(numPoints):
    data = np.linspace(0,1,numPoints)
    dataset = dict({'points': data})
    labels = []
    for d in data:
        labels.append(1)
    return tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dataset, np.array(labels)))

def input_train_set():
    dataset = basic_dataset(11)
    return dataset.repeat(100).shuffle(1000).batch(1)

point = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('points')
estimator = tf.estimator.DNNRegressor(feature_columns = [point],hidden_units = [100,100,100], label_dimension = 1)

estimator.train(input_fn = input_train_set)
```

Answer (score 0):

Main problem in your code was you were sending the data in dataset as simple tensors. But it input data in dataset should be dictionary with key name same as that with what was used in feature column. Apart, from that I have added extra dimension in input data. The following code will work.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

### DEFINE NEW MAP FUNCTION
def map_fn(d, l):
    return {'points': d}, l

def input_evaluation_set():
    data = [0.0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1]
    labels = []
    for d in data:
        labels.append(1)

    ### CHANGE STARTS HERE
    data = np.array(data)
    data = np.expand_dims(data, axis=-1)
    labels = np.array(labels)
    labels = np.expand_dims(labels, axis=-1)
    ### CHANGE ENDS HERE

    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.constant(data), tf.constant(labels)))

    ### CREATE DICTIONARY PAIR IN INPUT DATA
    dataset = dataset.map(map_fn)
    return dataset

point = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('points')
estimator = tf.estimator.DNNRegressor(feature_columns = [point],hidden_units = [100,100,100])

estimator.train(input_fn = input_evaluation_set)
```

Comment: Sorry, but this solution does not work on my computer. It throws another Error: ValueError: features should be a dictionary of 'Tensor's. Given type: class 'NoneType'

Comment: Can you tell me which version of TensorFlow you are using? Also, did you run the same code what I have given or you had added some own logic in my code?

Comment: I have tensorflow 1.14.0 installed. And I just copied your code without adding anything

Comment: I tested it on TensorFlow 2.0.0-rc0. TensorFlow 1.x has many other dependencies issues like `estimator` comes under `contrib` and all. I strongly suggest you to install TensorFlow 2.0 version. You can install it as `pip install tensorflow==2.0.0-rc0`. You will have no problems with it.

Comment: Now I installed 2.0.0-rc0 but I still get the same Error. What am I doing wrong?